# Show that $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a convergent sequence in $R^\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Suppose that $(x_n)$ is a sequence satisfying $|| x_{n+1}-x_n || < 1/ 5^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Show that $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a convergent sequence in $R^\mathbb{N}$.

At first my idea was to prove that $(x_n)_n \in \mathbb{N}$ it is from Cauchy. I need help please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376818/how-to-show-if-a-n1-a-n-le-frac12n-then-the-sequence-is-cauchy)

Comment: Why are you asking the same question twice? : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4629310/let-x-nn%e2%88%88n-be-a-sequence-in-rn-such-that-for-all-n-%e2%88%88-n-%e2%88%a5x-n1-%e2%88%92-x-n%e2%88%a5-1-5n

Answer (score 0):

Yes, actually you know from here that $\sum x_{n+1}-x_n$ is normally convergent and so $\sum x_{n+1} -x_n$ is convergent, so $(x_n)$.

Comment: The question is both  a duplicate and a question without context. Please do not answer such questions.